# WS-A between java and .net

Tags: java, .net, web-services

I have a web-service, which uses Web Service Addressing. It is written in .NET platform, I've imported it into my application via wsimport, JAX-WS included in JDK 1.6.0_24. It works somehow, but some operations fail, in the .net client log I see the next error message:

> Communication exception System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: A reply
>   message was received for operation 'UpdateMatchState' with action
>   'Mystuff:IQuoteReceiver:UpdateMatchStateResponse'. However, your
>   client code requires action
>   'Mystuff/IQuoteReceiver/UpdateMatchStateResponse'.

Seems they use different standard, .net client expect slashes, but java client sends colons. Any ideas in which direction should I dig to make it work?

**Update:**

Ok, after investigation of a source code, I've found part which does it ([W3CAddressingWSDLParserExtension](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/xml/ws/wsdl/parser/W3CAddressingWSDLParserExtension.java.html)):

```
protected static final String buildAction(String name, WSDLOperation o, boolean isFault) {
    String tns = o.getName().getNamespaceURI();

    String delim = SLASH_DELIMITER;

    // TODO: is this the correct way to find the separator ?
    if (!tns.startsWith("http"))
        delim = COLON_DELIMITER;
...
}
```

So, if web service type namespace starts with `http`, it uses slashes as delimiter, otherwise it uses colons, meanwhile .NET uses slashes only. So much magic!

Comment: Is it an old-school Web Service or WCF?

Comment: @Turowicz I am not sure. I was given the .net app. how to check? One thing I know it uses SOAP 1.2 protocol, because wsimport warned about some "non-standard extensions".

Comment: When me and my friend tried to consume a WCF from Java we had to use some manual approach (the auto generated jax didnt help much) http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/WSfromJava.aspx

Comment: you can also try kSoap http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Turowicz I've used the Apache CXF, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in my question, the problem is in JAX-WS implementation bundled in the JDK, either patch it (using endorsed) or just use Apache CFX, it works better.